# How Long does it take to Reach a Limiting Distribution?

Tags: probability

For Markov Chains, there are well known formulae  (e.g. fundamental matrix approach, first step analysis) which show us how to calculate the Expected Time to Absorption (e.g https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain). That is,  given a transition matrix and the current state - how many iterations (i.e. steps) are required (on average) for the chain to reach a certain state.

In a Markov Chain, we can define the following:

1. Define the Limiting Distribution $\pi(n)$ as:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \pi(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \pi(0) P^n $$

Where:

- $\pi(0)$ is the initial distribution.
- $P$ is the transition probability matrix of the Markov chain.

2. Define the Stationary Distribution $\pi$ as:

$$\pi P^n = \pi$$

Where:

- $P$ is the transition probability matrix of the Markov chain.

**Based on these concepts, I have the following question:**

Just as we have formulae to calculate the Expected Time to Absorption - given a Markov Chain with a given Transition Matrix and initial Distribution, can we derive analytical formulae to calculate the **Expected Time to reach the Limiting Distribution** and the **Expected Time to reach the Stationary Distribution** (provided these distributions exist)? How can this be done?

- Note 1: **My idea of doing this would be to first determine the Limiting Distribution and Stationary Distributions (if they exist) by solving the respective equations. Then, I would use the absorption Markov formulae to determine the number of steps needed to reach these distributions. Is this correct?**
- Note 2: The Limiting Distribution is more "powerful" than the Stationary Distribution. If a Limiting Distribution exists, then the Stationary Distribution follows the same distribution. However, if the Stationary Distribution exists, the same can not be said about the Limiting Distribution.
- Note 3 (Stationary Distributions): I know that Stationary Distributions are generally written as $\pi P = \pi$, but I prefer writing $\pi P^n = \pi$ as it is more logical to me. If you happen to "stumble into" a Stationary Distribution - you will be there forever (i.e. still be there even after $n$ steps).

I believe that both formulations are equivalent - see below:

$$\pi P = \pi$$
$$\pi P^2 = \pi P = \pi$$
$$ \pi P^3 = \pi P^2 P = \pi P^2 = \pi$$
$$\pi P^n = \pi$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, any existing limiting distribution must be stationary, see for instance [**1**] for a more detailed discussion of this. Conversely, there may exist a stationary distribution but no limiting distribution for a Markov chain. Hence, let's consider convergence towards the stationary distribution.

Second, Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ if and only if it is irreducible and all of its states are positive recurrent. (Any finite-state irreducible chain is positive recurrent.) Assume that this holds, and thus $\pi$ is a stationary distribution that is unique. By definition, $\pi$ is stationary if it is unaffected by the action of transition matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, that is:
$$
P^{T} \pi = 1 \pi
$$

this implies that $\pi$ is an eigenvector of $P$ with corresponding eigenvalue 1. Since $\pi$ is unique, the eigenvalue 1 is also unique. It can be shown that all other eigenvalues have norm strictly less than 1:
$$
\lambda_{1} = 1 > |\lambda_{2}| \geq \dots \geq |\lambda_{n}|.
$$

See for example Chapter 2 in [**2**] for an introduction to discrete time Markov Chains. Note that,

- $n$ usually stands for the size of the state space;
- and $t = 0, 1, \dots$ is used for time, i.e. the number of steps;
- $p_{i}(t)$ is the probability to be in a given state $i = 1, \dots, n$ at time $t$;
- and $p(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the entire distribution at time $t$.

Now, assuming that transition matrix $P$ is diagonalizable, it can be decomposed as:
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
u_{1} & \dots & u_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_{1} & & 0 \\
     & \ddots & \\
    0 & & \lambda_{n}
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_{1}\\
\vdots\\
v_{n}
\end{pmatrix}  .
$$

and we can write:
\begin{align*}
p(t)^{T} &= p(0)^{T} P^{t} \\
&= p(0)^{T} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T} \\
&= p(0)^{T} \lambda_{1}^{t} u_{1} v_{1}^{T} + p(0)^{T} \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T} \\
&= p(0)^{T} 1 \pi^{T} + p(0)^{T} \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T} \\
&= \pi^{T} + p(0)^{T} \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T}
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} p(t)^{T} = \pi^{T}$, since $|\lambda_{i}| < 1$ for all $i > 1$, and all other terms cancel out in the limit.

**The rate of convergence towards the stationary distribution.** Consider the following error:
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
E(t) &= \norm{\pi^{T} - p(t)^{T}} \\
&= \norm{\pi^{T} - 
\left(\pi^{T} + p(0)^{T} \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T}\right)} \\
&= \norm{p(0)^{T} \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T}} \\
&= \norm{p(0)^{T} \lambda_{2} u_{r} v_{2}^{T} +
p(0)^{T} \sum_{i=3}^n \lambda_{i}^{t} u_{i} v_{i}^{T}} \\
&\approx |\lambda_{2}^{t}| \norm{p(0)^{T} u_{r} v_{2}^{T}}
\end{align*}
This implies that the convergence rate is determined by the second largest eigenvalue. Since the error $E(t)$ decays exponentially with $|\lambda_{2}^{t}|$. The rate of decay is $- \ln(|\lambda_{2}|)$ and timescale is $- 1 / \ln(|\lambda_{2}|)$. In other words, the number of steps needed to come close to the stationary distribution is at least $- 1 / \ln(|\lambda_{2}|)$. Note also that if you start with initial distribution $p(0) \approx \pi^{T}$, then convergence is immediate.

Finally, if $P$ is not diagonalizable, one needs to start with the Jordan normal form of $P$ to arrive at a similar result; see [**3**].

### References:

[**1**] Convergence Rate of Markov Chains by Jeffrey S. Rosenthal.
http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/eigen.pdf

[**2**] Lecture Notes on Stochastic Processes by Frank Noé, Bettina Keller and Jan-Hendrik Prinz
https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/wiki/pub/CompMolBio/MarkovKetten15/stochastic_processes_2011.pdf

[**3**] On the Importance of the Second Largest Eigenvalue on the
Convergence Rate of Genetic Algorithms by Florian Schmitt and Franz Rothlauf
https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/2955239.2955324